# Can you restrict the application installation to iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Can you restrict the application installation to iPhone?  We have an app (.ipa) and we want it to be installable on iPhones only and not ipad. If there is any setting on ipa level so that we would make it available for iphones only?

Comment: I assume you deploy via iTunes store?

Although you can build a iOS apps specially for iPad, im pretty sure you can't do that the other way around. Obviously a iPhone app can fit on a iPad screen (screen real-estate wise) but that doesn't work vice-versa.

Question is why would you be so focused on this? What does it matter that a iPhone app, is running on a iPhone?

Comment: You could force to check for Telephony Capacity/SIM for instance (or other stuff), like WhatsApp, but with Handoff, I don't know if it's still valuable. But clearly, why not allow iPads?